# How to dynamically construct a multidimentional array or object in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Here is my code: (I am trying to dynamically construct an associative array in angularJs)

```
  $scope.details = {"profilesFound": [
    "https: //twitter.com/alexandreagular",
    "https: //twitter.com/?profile_id=46130006",
    "https: //facebook.com/1290628666",
    "https: //twitter.com/intent/user?user_id=84326171",
    "https: //www.linkedin.com/in/alex",
    "https: //www.linkedin.com/in/alexandreagular",
    "https: //www.facebook.com/alexandre.agular",
    "https: //www.facebook.com/alexandre"
  ]};

  $scope.socialProfiles = [];
  var spLength = $scope.details.profilesFound.length;

  for(var i=0;i<spLength;i++){
    var url = $scope.details.profilesFound[i];
    var domain = url.replace('.com','').replace('http://www.','').replace('https://www.','').replace('http://','').replace('https://','').split(/[/?#]/)[0];
    $scope.socialProfiles[domain]=url;
  }
```

I would like to construct an array as below

```
 "profilesFound":{
"facebook":[
  "https://facebook.com/1290628666",
  "https://www.facebook.com/alexandre.agular"
],
"twitter":[
  "https: //twitter.com/alexandreagular",
  "https: //twitter.com/?profile_id=46130006",
  "https: //twitter.com/intent/user?user_id=84326171"
],
"linkedin":[
  "https: //linkedin.com/1290628666",
  "https: //www.linkedin.com/alexandre.agular"
]
```

}

But this is what I get as result.

```
[twitter: "https://twitter.com/intent/user?user_id=84326171", facebook: "https://www.facebook.com/alexandre.agular", linkedin: "https://www.linkedin.com/in/alexandreagular"]
```

Please give me a solution. Thanks.

Comment: just initialize `$scope.socialProfiles[domain]` as an empty array and push urls into it instead of setting it to a url

Comment: Thanks rob, It works.

Answer (score 0):

You are reassigning $scope.socialProfiles[domain] for each new website, instead of appending to it.

instead of

```
$scope.socialProfiles[domain]=url;
```

try

```
if(!$scope.socialProfiles[domain])
    $scope.socialProfiles[domain] = []

$scope.socialProfiles[domain].push(url);
```

Comment: Thanks Zach, It looks simple and perfect.

Answer (score 0):

```
$scope.details = {
    profilesFound: [
      "https://twitter.com/alexandreagular",
      "https://twitter.com/?profile_id=46130006",
      "https://facebook.com/1290628666",
      "https://twitter.com/intent/user?user_id=84326171",
      "https://www.linkedin.com/in/alex",
      "https://www.linkedin.com/in/alexandreagular",
      "https://www.facebook.com/alexandre.agular",
      "https://www.facebook.com/alexandre"
    ]
  },
  $scope.socialProfiles = {};

$scope.details.profilesFound.forEach(function(profile) {
  var domain = profile.replace('.com', '').replace('http://www.', '').replace('https://www.', '').replace('http://', '').replace('https://', '').split(/[/?#]/)[0];
    $scope.socialProfiles[domain] = $scope.socialProfiles[domain] || [];
  $scope.socialProfiles[domain].push(profile);
});
```

Comment: Instead of using 
**$scope.socialProfiles[domain] = $scope.socialProfiles[domain] || [];** ,
 Using 
**if(!$scope.socialProfiles[domain])
    $scope.socialProfiles[domain] = []**

may avoid the unnecessary re-asignment of $scope.socialProfiles[domain].

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$scope.details = {"profilesFound": [
    "https://twitter.com/alexandreagular",
    "https://twitter.com/?profile_id=46130006",
    "https://facebook.com/1290628666",
    "https://twitter.com/intent/user?user_id=84326171",
    "https://www.linkedin.com/in/alex",
    "https://www.linkedin.com/in/alexandreagular",
    "https://www.facebook.com/alexandre.agular",
    "https://www.facebook.com/alexandre"
  ]};
    $scope.object = {};
   $scope.details.profilesFound.forEach(function (item, index) {
    var base = item.split('.com');
    var root = base[0].replace('http://www.', '').replace('https://www.','').replace('http://', '').replace('https://','');

    if(typeof $scope.object[root] !== 'undefined') $scope.object[root].push(item);

    else $scope.object[root] = [item];

    console.log($scope.object);
   });
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/v9c1uv5f/) is a working fiddle

Comment: Thanks Justin Herter, Great Solution.